# Server greetings

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make server greetings message but it doesn't even work for me, I saw that you can try to do this using `ch.name === 'name'` but I want my bot to send message to channel with specific id

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.id === `channel-id`);
  if (!channel) return;
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to do it when a user joins? I only ask this because I am not sure why you're looking for the channel

Comment: Which part isn't working? And btw if you are using `ch.id`, it can only find the channel on your guild (member.guild), because no other guild has a channel with exactly that ID. Every channel has a different ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to turn on Privileged Gateway Intents on the Dev Portal (https://discord.com/developers/applications)
[gateway intents on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pkgr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable intents for the guildMemberAdd event to emit. Make sure to enable them at [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

after enabling intents, you can add intents to your client by doing

```js
 const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS']} });
```