# Please can someone fix my Discord.js Code, is for my bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i'm making a discord bot for my server. i need to say "Hi" to new members.

I'm asking if someone can help me with this part of code, it doesn't work like the way i want.

```js
 client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
   var channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === ('709535738223657124'))
   channel.send(`Welcome to the server, my sweet ${member}`)
  });
```

the way that i want is to send that message to a specific channel. i thought it was another problem but i lack of options at the moment.

by the way i'm not a programer so if you can give me de fixed code i'll appreciate a lot <3

thanks!

Comment: This question looks [oddly familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646327/server-greetings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
   var channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '709535738223657124')
   channel.send(`Welcome to the server, my sweet ${member}`)
  });
```

You just had to add `.cache` before `find` in `channel`. And `member` will mention the user.